# AccessibleEngineSearch - cannot be removed from MAC

Tags: macos, malware

It looks like a program called AccessibleEngineSearch starts on the 8080 port each time I start my mac.

I tried to use Terminal and find the location of the file and delete it, but it still starts up.

Is there a way to stop this starting up?  Even if I kill the process, it restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem kind of the same. Then [this](https://macsecurity.net/view/382-remove-default-search-engine-mac) solved my issue
 If you are still having troubles, check out these folders for recently added files. I you think it is a malware or not a normal/default file delete it:

```
~/Library/Application Support
/Library/LaunchAgents
~/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons
Applications
```

Malwares are hard to recognize. check if above folders has these files:
com.pcv.hlpramc.plist, com.updater.mcy.plist, com.avickUpd.plist, and com.msp.agent.plist. if yes then remove them

You can also use apps like [Combo Cleaner](https://link.safecart.com/2runpe?en&clickId=ideashrd&subId2=finalchecktxt) for automatic check up and removal of malwares. I've used it and it just felt Awesome.

Another way is to clear the cache. It might crashes the malware.
Also Check Login Items
Remove all website data and reset all browsers
*That Should Do It*
Else don't worry it is not a malware it might be an application adware or something else

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for this. I bought MalwareBytes and in its first clean up run, it detected the issue and fixed it!!